# How to create custom JSP in Documentum web publisher?

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5

I'm trying to create a web page where some content(parts of the page such as footer/header etc) will come from documentum and some data on the page will com from external oracle database.

From what I can tell from Documentum Web publisher docs it seems like I should create a "presentation" that is JSP rather than XSL, but I am not able to figure out how to do that.

Is this the correct approach or is there a better approach? Is there a link to clear sample? Can all this be published into documentum from the web publisher frontend, or do I need direct access to documentum server(via unix etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work in webpublisher, key was to create a presentation file that when applied will publish as a JSP rendering, JSP code is embedded in the XSL presentation file. Was not very difficult, just not easy to find in the myriad of documentation that Documentum webpublisher comes with.
[Documentation](https://community.emc.com/thread/48954)

Comment: this helps no one what so ever,  atleast put a link to documentation place!